# typescript generates unexpected javascript [angularjs] module structure

Tags: angularjs, typescript1.5

I'm trying to convert an angular 1.4 app to be sourced in typescript but the generated file is not generated as I expected.

The expected generated call should look like this:

```
  //<module>.<service>.<method>
  appServicesUser.UserService.validateDmpeLogin($scope.credentials);
```

but while debugging, appServicesUser.UserService is undefined and inspecting appServicesUser shows it to be structured like this:

```
   //<module>.<method> where did the UserService "class" go?
   appServicesUser.validateDmpeLogin
```

validateDmpeLogin is not defined as a function. I'm not sure where my error lies in defining the typescript file. My goal is to have the generated javascript match the function I stated earlier.

Here is the ts file:

```
  // some of the details were excluded for brevity's sake
  module appServices {
   'use strict'

   export interface IUserService {
      validateDmpeCredentials(userCreds: UserCredentials): ng.IPromise<IUser>
   }
   class UserService implements IUserService {
      static $inject = ['$http'];

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService){

    }

    validateDmpeCredentials(userCreds: UserCredentials): ng.IPromise<IUser>{
            return this.$http.post('api/user/ValidateCredentials/', userCreds)
                    .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IUser>): IUser => {
                        return response.data;
                    });
      }
    }

    angular
      .module('appServices', [])
      .service('appServices.UserService', UserService);

  }
```

The generated js file:

```
  var appServices;
  (function (appServices) {
    'use strict';
     //excluded details for brevity's sake
     ......

      var UserService = (function () {
      function UserService($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
      }
      UserService.prototype.validateDmpeCredentials = function (userCreds) {
        return this.$http.post('api/user/ValidateCredentials/', userCreds)
            .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
      };
       UserService.$inject = ['$http'];
       return UserService;
   })();

   angular
     .module('appServices', [])
     .service('appServices.UserService', UserService);
   })(appServices || (appServices = {}));
```

..and finally the app module, 'appServices' is last param

```
  var appRoot = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute','ngMessages', 'ngTouch', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'appServices']);
```

[UPDATED] controller injection & calling code:

```
   appRoot.controller('DMPEController', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', '$scope',  '$http', '$q', '$log', '$filter', 'appServicesUser', function ($timeout, $rootScope, $scope, $http, $q, $log, $filter, appServicesUser){

  ....
   //calling code
   appServicesUser.UserService.validateDmpeLogin($scope.credentials)
            .success(function(requestorResp) {
               .....
```

Comment: Where is the calling code? What's the point of `export interface IUserService`? After all, you use the service only through dependency injection. So your call would look something like `UserService.validateDmpeLogin($scope.credentials)`, or, using your description, `<service>.<method>`.

Comment: Hello @zeroflagL. The goal of using interfaces is to enforce consistency and take advantage of typescript's support of interfaces. There are going to be several developers working on this and we're trying to make the codebase less painful to support down the road. We're all learning together so just trying to do it "right". The calling code, it looks the same as the expected method (like the current code looks like, just a wrapper to $http)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The user service will be directly injected into a controller (or some other artifact), so I still don't understand how you get to something like `appServicesUser.UserService`.

Comment: Sorry @zeroflagL, I'm not understanding your question/point. The service is being injected into a controller. I've tried appServicesUser.UserService.validateDmpeLogin and just starting from the service name UserService.validateDmpeLogin. I have to call the function somehow. When I try to inspect the UserService it is undefined. So either my typescript definition is jacked or I'm injected it incorrectly - that's what I can't figure out. Looks right to me but obviously not.

Comment: You registered the service as `'appServices.UserService'` so you would also inject it using that name: `appRoot.controller('DMPEController', ['appServices.UserService'..., function(UserService, ...`